# Existence of a Path from Initial to Accepting Configuration in Turing Machine Runs: A Reduction-Based Proof

Tags: graphs, turing-machines, reductions, mathematical-programming, path

Is it possible to show, by reduction(Reduction in the length of the path and the running time), that for a Turing machine M and an input X, there exists a run in which M accepts X if and only if there is a path from the initial configuration in M's run on X to some accepting configuration

Comment: sounds like it's true by definition iiuc, am i missing something?